# how to make the interval value dynamic and random every loop of setInterval NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf

I have a function that generates a random number from 3 to 5 (including 3 and 5) and I want the setInterval that triggers a function in nodeJS in loop to have its interval value received from another function and that each time the loop occurs in setInterval the value is different (random).

```
bot.start(async (ctx, next) => {

    ctx.reply(`Se preparem para os sinais! proximo sinal em alguns minutos`)

    if ( paused == false) {
        setInterval(() => {
            bot.telegram.sendMessage(process.env.TELEGRAM_CHANNEL, ' APOSTE AGORA \n\n* Analisar as rodadas anteriores pra saber se vai entrar 10 segundos antes ou 10 segundos depois. *\n\nSaque automático 1.5x \n\nMax 2x\n\n50% de saque ativado em 1.3x\n\n*Gerenciamento de banca, se perder a culpa não é minha!*\n\nVamos pra cima voadores\n\n✅\n'
            );
        }, getRandomInterval(3,5) * 1000);
    }
    next();
})
```

```
function getRandomInterval(min, max) {
    let randomInterval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    console.log('linha 92: ' + randomInterval)
    return randomInterval;
}
```

Comment: What? You want a random "setInterval" So no "interval" more like a delay like `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is the perfect candidate for this.

```js
bot.start(async(ctx, next) => {

  ctx.reply(`Se preparem para os sinais! proximo sinal em alguns minutos`)

  if (paused == false) {
    function foo_interval_action() {
      bot.telegram.sendMessage(process.env.TELEGRAM_CHANNEL, ' APOSTE AGORA ');
      setTimeout(foo_interval_action,  getRandomInterval(3, 5) * 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(foo_interval_action,  getRandomInterval(3, 5) * 1000);
  }
  next();
})

function getRandomInterval(min, max) {
  let randomInterval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  // console.log('linha 92: ' + randomInterval)
  return randomInterval;
}
```

Here's a generic function to generate variable delay interval. Nothing fancy.

```js
function setVariableInterval(foo_do_action, foo_get_delay) {

  function do_it() {
    foo_do_action();
    setTimeout(do_it, foo_get_delay())
  }

  // right away
  do_it()
}


var foo_get_delay = function() {
  return Math.random() * 3000 + 250
}

var foo_do_action = function() {
  console.log("time now is: " + new Date())
}

setVariableInterval(foo_do_action, foo_get_delay)
```